# I have a list of files, how can I open and copy the contents of each file to a new one using bash?

Tags: bash

I'm running simulations and I want to write scripts which make data evaluation much faster.
I have a list of files. I used this command to generate it:

```
echo ( find "../../../Single conical/IV/" -name "current-tot.dat" ) > IVfilenames.dat
```

I want to open them one by one and copy their content into a new file (lets call it results.dat), but I don't know how to do it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: That command gives a syntax error. I think you just wrote `(` instead of `$(`.

Comment: You do not need to open the files, just concoct them. `find "../../../Single conical/IV/" -name "current-tot.dat" -print0 | xargs -0 -I file cat file > merged.file`

Comment: @wjandrea it depends. If OP is using the fish shell, the command is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the `echo` out of your command. I don't know why you had it there in the first place.

```sh
find "../../../Single conical/IV/" -name "current-tot.dat" > IVfilenames.dat
```

Then `IVfilenames.dat` will be a list of files like this:

```
../../../Single conical/IV/Dir1/current-tot.dat
../../../Single conical/IV/Dir2/current-tot.dat
```

You can use the below code to compile all the `current-tot.dat` files from the list into one `results.dat` file:

```sh
while read -r filename; do 
    cat "$filename"
done < IVfilenames.dat > results.dat
```

---

But that said, it's easier to cut out the middleman, and not create the list of files at all:

```sh
find "../../../Single conical/IV/" -name "current-tot.dat" -exec cat -- {} + > results.dat
```

Comment: @david-foerster Thanks for the edit. That was exactly what I was just looking for.